# How to specify not full path for pandas.read_csv()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, traceback

I'm working with [this tutorial](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/), and I'm using pandas to go through.

This is the code fragment I typed and received an error:

```
users = pd.read_csv('ml-100k//u.users', sep = '|', names = ['User ID', 'Age','Gender', 'Occupation','Zip Code'])
```

Error produced by code above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    users = pd.read_csv('ml-100k//u.users', sep = '|', names = ['User ID', 'Age','Gender', 'Occupation','Zip Code'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 709, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 449, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 818, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1049, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1695, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 402, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 718, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: File b'ml-100k//u.users' does not exist
```

---

I figured it out how to make it work by writing:

```
users = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python3\\ml-100k\\ml-100k\\u.user', sep = '|', names = ['User ID', 'Age','Gender', 'Occupation','Zip Code'])
```

Is there an easier way to do this without writing in full file path? I use a Windows 64 Pro.

Comment: if you start the python shell from the `ml-100k` folder, you can just specify the file name rather than the entire path as the working directory will be `c:\...\ml-100k\`

Comment: `'ml-100k//u.users'` - The problem may be the two forward slashes. Try a single forward slash. In windows you can use a single forward slash `/` or double backslash `\\\` as a separator. Or, if you make it a raw string, a single backslash `r"\"`,

Answer (score 1):

I find usefull to work with the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module. I create `Path` objects on top of my scripts (or in a dedicated file) like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
path_1 = Path(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Python3\ml-100k\ml-100k') # absolute path
path_2 = Path.cwd() # current working directory
```

Then this is helpfull for the rest of your scripts. You can use these objects like so:

```
user = pd.read_csv(path_2.joinpath('u.users'), sep = '|', names = ['User ID', 'Age','Gender', 'Occupation','Zip Code'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to specify path in [`pandas.read_csv()` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **filepath_or_buffer** : *[`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path), [`py._path.local.LocalPath`](https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html#py._path.local.LocalPath) or any object with a `read()` method (such as a file handle or [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO))*
>
> The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local file could be file `://localhost/path/to/table.csv`

- > *class* `pathlib.Path(*pathsegments)`
  >
  > A subclass of [`PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath), this class represents concrete paths of the system’s path flavour (instantiating it creates either a [`PosixPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) or a [`WindowsPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath)):
  >
  > ```
  > >>> Path('setup.py')
  > PosixPath('setup.py')
  > ```
  >
  > *pathsegments* is specified similarly to [`PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath).
- > *class* `pathlib.WindowsPath(*pathsegments)`
  >
  > A subclass of [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) and [`PureWindowsPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PureWindowsPath), this class represents concrete Windows filesystem paths:
  >
  > ```
  > >>> WindowsPath('c:/Program Files/')
  > WindowsPath('c:/Program Files')
  > ```
  >
  > *pathsegments* is specified similarly to [`PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath).
- > *class* **`io.TextIOBase`**
  >
  > Base class for text streams. This class provides a character and line based interface to stream I/O. There is no `readinto()` method because Python’s character strings are immutable. It inherits [IOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase). There is no public constructor.
  >   [`TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) provides or overrides these data attributes and methods in addition to those from [`IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase):
  >
  > **`read(size)`**
  >
  > Read and return at most *`size`* characters from the stream as a single [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). If *`size`* is negative or `None`, reads until EOF.

TextIOBase provides or overrides these data attributes and methods in addition to those from IOBase:

Also I've found [question about path specifying in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python#2953843), answers say, that it can be done in several ways:

- > you can use always:
  >
  > ```
  > 'C:/mydir'
  > ```
- > this works both in linux and windows. Other posibility is
  >
  > ```
  > 'C:\\mydir'
  > ```
- > if you have problems with some names you can also try raw strings:
  >
  > ```
  > r'C:\mydir'
  > ```
- > however best practice is to use the os.path module functions that
  >   always select the correct configuration for your OS:
  >
  > ```
  > os.path.join(mydir, myfile)
  > ```

---

**TLDR**: Easiest and least complex way is by specifying path variable as

```
CSV_FILE = r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Python3\ml-100k\ml-100k\u.user'
```

or

```
CSV_FILE = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python3\\ml-100k\\ml-100k\\u.user'
```

and better, though still easy way would be

```
CSV_FILE = os.path.join('C:', 'Users', 'User', 'Documents', 'Python3', 'ml-100k', 'ml-100k', 'u.user')
```

you can also specify path relatively to your working directory (for example if you have your script in `C:\Users\User\Documents\Python3\ml-100k\ml-100k`, you could simply specify filename:

```
CSV_FILE = 'u.user'
```

also you can specify URL, like mentioned on the top.